# How to Get the Tag Identifier in Core NFC

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

How can I get the ID of an NFC tag (not the ID of the message payload) using Core NFC?

I am looking for something similiar to this function that exists in Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId()

Comment: Did you have any solution?

Comment: I did not. I have found this article that provides possible reasons behind Apple's decision to hide this ability to developers: https://www.taptrack.com/article/blog/core-nfc-2/

Answer (score 2):

The use of _foundTags *will* cause rejection:

> 1.2 Binary Rejected
>
> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> _foundTags
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If you are using third-party libraries, please update to the most
>   recent version of those libraries. If you do not have access to the
>   libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using
>   the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These tools can help you narrow down where the problematic
>   code resides. You could also use the "nm" tool to verify if any
>   third-party libraries are calling these APIs.
>
> Resources
>
> For information on the "nm" tool, please review the "nm tool" Xcode
>   manual page.
>
> If there are no alternatives for providing the functionality your app
>   requires, you can file an enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve it.
But keep in mind that it uses a private function, that can be removed / changed at any time by Apple, and can cause rejection from the AppStore.

Tested in my app, it works for now with iOs 11.1

The sources :

https://github.com/hansemannn/iOS11-NFC-Example/issues/16

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/pull/287/files#diff-84fad93feff6a327c30a08cac8f546dfR171

```
        func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
            let uid : String = getTagIdFromSession(session: session)
            //Do what you want with the UID

        }


        func getTagIdFromSession(session : NFCNDEFReaderSession) -> String{
            var uid: String = ""
            if(session.value(forKey: "_foundTags") != nil) {
                let foundTags : NSArray = session.value(forKey: "_foundTags") as! NSArray
                if(foundTags.count > 0) {
                    let tag : NSObject = foundTags.firstObject  as! NSObject;
                    if(tag.value(forKey: "_tagID") != nil) {
                        var uuidPadded : Data = tag.value(forKey: "_tagID") as! Data
                        //We reverse the order
                        for (i,_) in uuidPadded.enumerated() {
                            uuidPadded.insert(uuidPadded.remove(at:i),at:0)
                        }
                        for (_, element) in uuidPadded.enumerated() {
                            let tag : String = String(element, radix:16)
                            //We add the missing 0 in case the number is < 10. It can be done with bitwise operations too.  
                            if(tag.length < 2) {
                                uid.append("0"+tag)
                            }
                            else {
                                uid.append(tag)
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return uid;
        }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the recent answer, this will call app rejection.